# I'd like to see an example of a function name being ignored in a nested-name-specifier

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, name-lookup

Foot note (33) in page 53 of N4140:

> Lookups in which function names are ignored include names appearing in
>   a *nested-name-specifier*, an *elaborated-type-specifier*, or a
>   *base-specifier*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
namespace A
{
    void std();
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World"; // (1)
    }
};
```

In (1), `std` cannot name a function, thus the function `A::std` is ignored during lookup, and [the code compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8acb5389c9fbc6ec).
This rule is explicitly mentioned in [basic.lookup.qual]/1:

> If a `::` scope resolution operator in a *nested-name-specifier* is
>   not preceded by a *decltype-specifier*, **lookup of the name preceding
>   that `::` considers only namespaces, types, and templates whose
>   specializations are types.**

Another example from the list includes

```
class A : B {};
```

Here, `B` cannot designate a function, thus any functions called `B` are ignored during lookup. Same goes for

```
class A a;
```

Where `A` cannot name a function.

Comment: How an expression like `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` would find a function named `chrono`? Shouldn't the name to be found be located **after** the last `::` in the *nested-name-specifier*?

Comment: @Ayrosa I think you're a little bit confused. The nested-name-specifier is the bit before the last identifier, in this case `std::chrono::`. `chrono` must be found by lookup just as `high_resolution_clock` must be. Every name must be looked up, including `std` and `chrono`.

Comment: To be fair though, there cannot be a `std::chrono` function anyway, because you cannot have a function and a namespace with the same name in the same parent namespace. Perhaps `#include <utility>` / `namespace N { void std(); int zero() { return std::move(0); } } int main() { return N::zero(); }` makes for a good example?

Comment: @Columbo I think I finally understood your example. Even though `std()` is a member function of `A`, the code doesn't break in (1) because the name of the function `std` is ignored by the lookup for the name `std` started at the expression `std::cout << ...`.Is that correct?